# How to validate flutter text field for Email or Phone or Null?

Tags: flutter

How to validate same field for either email or phone or not null??

```
TextFormField(
                        
                        // validator: ???,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          hintText: "hint_phone_no_email_address",
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                        ),
                      ),
```

I want to validate when I press my button

```
RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
           // call validate function from here.....   
        },
        textColor: Colors.white,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
        child: Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color>[
                Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                Color(0xFF1976D2),
                Color(0xFF42A5F5),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          
          child:
              Text('Next', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
        ),
      ),
```

Please let me know...

Answer (score 9):

[image]

### 1. Define Validation methods

Here I use [email_validator](https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator) for verifying the emails and a Regular Expression for the phone numbers. You can either also check [intl_phone_field](https://pub.dev/packages/intl_phone_field) for the phone numbers, or [libphonenumber](https://pub.dev/packages/libphonenumber) (Though, not yet supported for Web or Desktop):

```
bool isEmail(String input) => EmailValidator.validate(input);

bool isPhone(String input) => RegExp(
  r'^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$'
).hasMatch(input);
```

### 2. Define your `TextFormField`

Then, in your `TextFormField`, define a `GlobalKey<FormFieldState>` and a `validator` where you test for both emails and phone numbers:

```
TextFormField(
  key: _key.value,
  validator: (value) {
    if (!isEmail(value) && !isPhone(value)) {
      return 'Please enter a valid email or phone number.';
    }
    return null;
  },
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    hintText: "Enter your phone number or email",
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
  ),
),
```

### 3. Validate the `TextFormField` on button press

When the user press the button, validate the `TextFormField` and navigate if valid.

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (_key.value.currentState.validate()) {
      // Navigate to next page
    }
  },
  style: ButtonStyle(
    padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.all(0.0)),
    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Color(0xFF0D47A1))
  ),
  child: Text('Next', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
),
```

### Full source code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_hooks/flutter_hooks.dart';
import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    ),
  );
}

bool isEmail(String input) => EmailValidator.validate(input);
bool isPhone(String input) =>
    RegExp(r'^[\+]?[(]?[0-9]{3}[)]?[-\s\.]?[0-9]{3}[-\s\.]?[0-9]{4,6}$')
        .hasMatch(input);

class HomePage extends HookWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _key = useState(GlobalKey<FormFieldState>());
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextFormField(
              key: _key.value,
              validator: (value) {
                if (!isEmail(value) && !isPhone(value)) {
                  return 'Please enter a valid email or phone number.';
                }
                return null;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                hintText: "Enter your phone number or email",
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (_key.value.currentState.validate()) {
                  // Navigate to next page
                }
              },
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(const EdgeInsets.all(0.0)),
                  foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
                  backgroundColor:
                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Color(0xFF0D47A1))),
              child: Text('Next', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: No.  Please don't use a small regex like this to match a valid email.  You'll be returning plenty of false negatives.  Instead, use https://pub.dev/packages/email_validator, which does it according to the spec, not according to just the forms you've seen.

Comment: This seems to be a very sound package for email validation, I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Wrap the textFormFields with a `Form`
2. Give the `Form` a key and create this key [_formKey] in `initState`
3. Create validator for each `TextFormField` that needs to be validated when your button is pressed.
4. Call `_formKey.currentState.validate()` which returns *`true`* if and only if **ALL** fields are validated otherwise *`false`*.

```dart
class _SomeClassState extends State<SomeClass>{
GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey;  // DECLARE a formKey
@override
void initState(){
   super.initState();
   _formKey = GlobalKey(); // INSTANTIATE the key here
   ...
}
/// 4. validate function
void validateController(){
   if(!_formKey.currentState.validate()){
      // value is false.. textFields are rebuilt in order to show errorLabels
      return;
   }
   // action WHEN values are valid
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){
return Scaffold(
    ...
   // 1. Form should be at the top of the widget tree
   Form(
    key: _formKey, // 2.
    child:
      ...
    TextFormField(
       validator:(string) => string.isEmpty // 3. add your validating function here
       decoration: InputDecoration(
         contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
         hintText: "hint_phone_no_email_address",
         filled: true,
         fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
       ),
   ),
   ...

   ...
   RaisedButton(
     onPressed: validateControllers, //4. calls function that validates [when button is pressed ONLY]
     textColor: Colors.white,
     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
     child: Container(
       decoration: const BoxDecoration(
         gradient: LinearGradient(
           colors: <Color>[
            Color(0xFF0D47A1),
            Color(0xFF1976D2),
            Color(0xFF42A5F5),
           ],
        ),
      ),  
       child: Text('Next', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
    ),
 ),
  ...
```

For section 3, where you plan to create a validator for either 'Email' or 'Phone number', you can use `RegExp`.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to validate many fields, it is advisable to use the `Form` widget

first make a `form key`

```
          final GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
        Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: Column(
    
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                            
                            validator: (String value) {
              if (value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Email is Required';
              }
              if (!RegExp(
                      r"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$")
                  .hasMatch(value)) {
                return 'Please enter a valid Email';
              }
              return null;
            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                              hintText: "hint_phone_no_email_address",
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                            ),
                          ),
                
    
    //validating when the raised button is pressed
    
    
        RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                   // call validate function from here..... 
                validateEmail(),  
                },
                textColor: Colors.white,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: Container(
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                      colors: <Color>[
                        Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                        Color(0xFF1976D2),
                        Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  
                  child:
                      Text('Next', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                ),
              ),
    
          validateEmail()async{
     FormState form = formKey.currentState;
        form.save();
        if (!form.validate()) {
          print('Invalid Email');
    }else{
print('Credentials are valid');
}
}
```

Comment: No. Please don't use a small regex like this to match a valid email. You'll be returning plenty of false negatives. Instead, use pub.dev/packages/email_validator, which does it according to the spec, not according to just the forms you've seen.