# How to UpperCase all the letters of a textField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a textField and I want to only accept UpperCase letters on it, so if I type 'asd' it have to be converted to 'ASD' in the field.

I already tried TextCapitalization.character but it keeps the caps lock activated and If I turn it off my next letters are showed in lower case. I don't want to accept lower case letters in any situation.

Is there a way to do it?

Edit - What I did

```dart
TextField(
      
        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.characters,
    )
```

Comment: can you give an example of what you already didi?

Comment: see my update .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate flutter text field for Email or Phone or Null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66307037/how-to-validate-flutter-text-field-for-email-or-phone-or-null)

Comment: No. I want to UpperCase all the letters inputed in the textfield

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter TextField value always uppercase & debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238908/flutter-textfield-value-always-uppercase-debounce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom `TextInputFormatter` inside `TextField( inputFormatters: [UppercaseInputFormatter()], ...)`

```dart
class UppercaseInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return newValue.copyWith(text: newValue.text.toUpperCase());
  }

}
```

Comment: And how can I use it in the textfield?

Comment: @HelloWorldd I updated my answer.